# Good map with hector_mapping and with odometry-only - poor map with gmapping

Tags: navigation, mapping, gmapping, xv-11-laser-driver, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using an XV11 lidar and calibrated odometry, I am able to build a good quality map using both hector_mapping (using scan results only) and pure odometry (using odometry only).
However, I am unable to get a good map using gmapping (which combines scan results and odometry).

***Odometry:***

My robot has odometry that passes the tests listed in the [navigation tuning guide](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide) - linear translation is perfect, rotation error seems to be reasonable as well.

***Lidar:***

Additionally, it is using an XV11 lidar as laser scanner, with the xv_11_laser_driver package.

***Bagfile:***

I've recorded a short bag file with /odom, /tf and /scan topics, using following command:

`rosbag record -O second_data /scan /tf /odom`

I then compressed the bagfile (`rosbag compress second_data.bag`), and put it available [here](https://github.com/KristofRobot/frobo/blob/master/bagfile/second_data.bag).

***Map results:***

If I transform this bag file into a map using **hector_mapping**, the result looks perfect: [image: image description]

EDIT: Here are links to the hector_mapping generated [pgm](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KristofRobot/frobo/master/bagfile/hector.pgm) and [yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KristofRobot/frobo/master/bagfile/hector.yaml) files.

Moreover, if I simply display the laserscan results in **rviz in the /odom** frame, with an infinite decay time, I get a very nice map as well:
[image: image description]

Now, when I try to run this through **gmapping**, the map looks very poor:
[image: image description]

EDIT: Here are links to the gmapping generated [pgm](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KristofRobot/frobo/master/bagfile/gmapping.pgm) and [yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KristofRobot/frobo/master/bagfile/gmapping.yaml) files.

***Commands:***

To generate the gmapping map, I used:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
rosparam set slam_gmapping/delta 0.1  #set resolution to 0.1
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan
rosbag play second_data.bag --clock
rosrun map_server map_saver
```

To generate the hector_mapping map, I used:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
roslaunch hector_mapping mapping_default.launch
rosbag play second_data.bag --clock
rosrun map_server map_saver
```

Launch file is available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KristofRobot/frobo/master/bagfile/mapping_default.launch).

PDF graph of tf tree is available [here](https://github.com/KristofRobot/frobo/raw/master/bagfile/frames.pdf).

***Question:***

How come gmapping gives such poor results, compared to the two other approaches?
Any suggestions to improve the gmapping results would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Kristof

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202196/good-map-with-hector_mapping-and-with-odometry-only---poor-map-with-gmapping/) by [Kristof](https://answers.ros.org/users/5409/kristof/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2015-02-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-02-07**:
I had a very similar experience with the xv-11 laser.  I got the best results from gmapping by driving my robot in a straight line, super slow (around 0.02 m/s I think).

**Comment by [Kristof](https://answers.ros.org/users/5409/kristof/) on 2015-02-07**:
@jseal interesting, thanks! Did you ever try setting the *minimumScore* parameter? Setting this to a very high value (see below) works very well for me.

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-02-07**:
I haven't, I'm not sure how I missed that one.  I'm going to give it a try.  I ended up stitching a couple of maps together with gimp to produce my final map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did a lot of different gmapping experiments - results can be found [here](https://github.com/KristofRobot/frobo/tree/master/bagfile).

**Summary of what I tried that did NOT help:**

- Decreasing *linear_update* and *angular_update* to 0.1 (from default 1.0) (Note: increasing to 2.0 works a little bit better, presumably because this means the laser scans have become more dissimilar before being processed)
- Increasing *particles* to 100, 500

**Summary of what did help:**

I had most success with setting the *minimumScore* to a very high value, as suggested [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/189159/bad-maps-produced-by-gmapping-in-simulation-with-feature-poor-environments/), and combining that with setting *srr/srt/str* to 0, and *stt* to 0.1 (to reflect rotational error, but near-perfect translational behavior), i.e.:

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan _delta:=0.1 _maxUrange:=4.99 _xmin:=-5.0 _ymin:=-5.0 _xmax:=5.0 _ymax:=5.0 _particles:=30 _srr:=0 _srt:=0 _str:=0 _stt:=0.1 _minimumScore:=10000
```

(Note that the *maxUrange*, and particles values are the defaults; the *xmin/ymin/xmax/ymax* just make for a smaller map, by specifying much lower starting values than the default 100m)

The result is this ([pgm](https://github.com/KristofRobot/frobo/raw/master/bagfile/gmapping_delta_0.1_minimumScore_10000_srr_srt_str_0_stt_0.1_particles_30_3.pgm)):
[image: image description]

Note that results change across runs - sometimes results would be slightly worse.
In particular, the  "_srr:=0 _srt:=0 _str:=0 _stt:=0.1" seems not very significant - with all these set to 0, and *particles* set to 1, that is with:

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan _delta:=0.1 _maxUrange:=4.99 _xmin:=-5.0 _ymin:=-5.0 _xmax:=5.0 _ymax:=5.0 _particles:=1 _srr:=0 _srt:=0 _str:=0 _stt:=0 _minimumScore:=10000
```

I get this ([pgm](https://github.com/KristofRobot/frobo/raw/master/bagfile/gmapping_delta_0.1_minimumScore_10000_srr_srt_stt_str_0_particles_1.pgm)):

[image: image_description]

Slightly different, but well within the variance I get by running the previous command.

Lastly, by simply using the defaults for *srr/srt/str/stt*, i.e.:

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan _delta:=0.1 _maxUrange:=4.99 _xmin:=-5.0 _ymin:=-5.0 _xmax:=5.0 _ymax:=5.0 _minimumScore:=10000
```

I get this ([pgm](https://github.com/KristofRobot/frobo/raw/master/bagfile/gmapping_delta_0.1_minimumScore_10000_2.pgm)):

[image: image_description]

Again slightly different, but well in line with what I get by running the first command.

So in summary, **changing *minimumScore* to a very large value solves my problem**. (I tried 500, 750, 1000, 10 000, with 10 000 best)

So this seems to solve my issue. I am still open to better solutions though, as this seems a bit of a hack, disabling a large part of gmapping's 'intelligence'.

---

Originally posted by [Kristof](https://answers.ros.org/users/5409/kristof/) with karma: 141 on 2015-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kristof](https://answers.ros.org/users/5409/kristof/) on 2015-02-07**:
The [documentation for minimumScore](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) ("*Can avoid jumping pose estimates [...] when using laser scanners with limited range (e.g. 5m).*") suggests this might be a common problem with xv11 lidars (5m range). Have other xv11 lidar users a similar experience with gmapping?

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-02-07**:
Hi @Kristof, it would be interesting to check for a slightly larger map the parameters you used. I think gmapping performs well when there are objects within the range of the sensor. For e.g.. in corridors it would be a different story, I will check by varying the minimumScore with my bagfile.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest going through [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/39132/improve-gmapping-results/).
Gmapping results depends a lot on different parameters specially number of particles used, linear update rate and angular update rate. Tweaking these parameters in the gmapping.launch file can produce little better result.

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kristof](https://answers.ros.org/users/5409/kristof/) on 2015-02-06**:
@AlexR, thanks I went through that answer, and in particular the reference to [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/189159/bad-maps-produced-by-gmapping-in-simulation-with-feature-poor-environments/) seems promising - still testing, but will report back shortly.